# make items from checkboxlist links to other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkboxlist.When I check one the value will appear in a table.Now I want that value and each value I check to make it a link.This is my code for getting the checked values:

```
foreach (ListItem item in check.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {


                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    TableCell celula = new TableCell();
                    celula.Style.Add("width", "200px");
                    celula.Style.Add("background-color", "red");

                    //celula.RowSpan = 2;
                    celula.Text = item.Value.ToString();




                    row.Cells.Add(celula);

                    this.tabel.Rows.Add(row);
```

Now I want the item.value to make it a link..I'm using c# in asp.net application

Comment: Add a Hyperlink control to the `celula.Controls` collection instead of setting the TableCell's Text property.

Comment: You want, open webbrowser when click on element in checkboxlist? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Hyperlink` control to the `celula.Controls` collection instead of setting the TableCell's `Text` property.

```
// Create a Hyperlink Web server control and add it to the cell.
System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink h = new HyperLink();
h.Text = item.Value;
string url = "~/Default.aspx?Item=" + Server.UrlEncode(item.Value);
h.NavigateUrl = url;
celula.Controls.Add(h);
```

Note that you need to recreate this table on every postback, so you might want to add this to `Page_PreRender` instead.

Comment: i made it like this: HyperLink link = new HyperLink();

                    link.Text = item.Value;
                    link.NavigateUrl ="Default.aspx";
                    celula.Controls.Add(link);                                                                                                                    Now I want in my Default.aspx page to get the item.value. So when I press an item the page Default.aspx will open and will appear: You've chosen item.Value

Comment: @Bibu: Edited my answer. Add the necessary information as querystring parameter(f.e. the ID of the item).

Comment: but how can i post the item.value to my default.aspx page?